# Using order_by in django based on the parameter passed in the url

Tags: django

I am working on a basic ecommerce django website and on my category page I have several options to sort the items. This is my urls.py:

```
path("category/<str:sort>",views.category,name="category"),
```

and this is my views.py:

def category(request,sort):

```
context = {
     
    'types' : Category.objects.all(),
    'prods': Product.objects.filter().order_by(),
    'cartItems':[],
   
}    
return render(request,"category.html",context)
```

Now my concern is that when a user chooses to sort the products , my field names of product model are quite big for eg. if a user chooses to sort by date then the name in my product model for date is "productaddedtimedate" and passing this in the url would look pretty inappropriate (category/productaddedtimedate). Also if he want to sort by reverse date then passing                    "-productaddedtimedate" (minus sign) will also not look good . So is there any fix to this like I can grab the parameter from the url and change it in views.py before using it in the context. For example I take parameter "date" in url and in views.py change it to productaddedtimedate then pass it in context.

Comment: create a look up function. so lets say you have a dict (`my_dict ={"date":"productaddedtimedate", "price":"whatever",...}`) and when the user enters "date" you write `my_dict["date"]` and it will return `productaddedtimedate`. just get the parameter from the url...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. For example if you want to have date for sorting by date in your url
then:

```
a=""
if parameter == "date"
    a="productaddedtimedate"

context = {
     
    'types' : Category.objects.all(),
    'prods': Product.objects.filter().order_by(a),
    'cartItems':[],
   
}    
return render(request,"category.html",context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the field name in your models.py file. and then remigrate it. It would be the simplest option.

Comment: Yes I already know that but I am having a large no. of models and I have already used them in many of my templates so I would take that as the last option

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this. in the context dictionary add `'date':'productaddedtimedate'` then use it in your template. but i am not sure if this will work